# RHEL kickstart adding RAID driver question

Tags: redhat, kickstart

I've an IBM X3550M3 which I want to kickstart over the network and install RHEL5.u4

I get so far then it cannot recognize the built-in raid device - it does this with a straight DVD hands on install too.

I've dug around the IBM site and found the drivers 
http://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/XSA/02dkt/1/ibm_dd_sraidmr_00.00.04.37_rhel5_32-64.txt

I understand I can use the kickstart directive to tell it where to find the RAID driver
devicedriver=path to device driver.img

What I'm not sure about is how I get the files from the downloaded RAID driver.iso  to become an .img file so I can load them with PXE kickstart.

Can anyone explain the process, or point to some docs ?

Regards
Andy

Comment: Can you mount the iso and see if the img file is supplied so you can extract it? `mount -o loopback disk.iso /mnt/someplace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to specify a driverdisk option:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#driverdisk

You probably will want to put them on your PXE server and serve them via http:

--source=

Specify a URL for the driver disk. NFS locations can be given with nfs:host:/path/to/img.

Otherwise, recreate your initrd following thses steps:

http://wiki.openvz.org/Modifying_initrd_image

Comment: Thanks I'd  figured that I needed to so something like that , but I'm not sure how I get the driver .iso to become a .img that that kicstart would look for , I take that they are not the same type of file ?

Comment: Mount the ISO like so and take a look at what's contained there.

mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
ls /mnt/cdrom

Comment: Thanks for the replies , I just added the .iso and it worked.